# Symfony website got broken once pushed in production

Tags: symfony-3.2

I'm developing a website using Symfony 3.2, and it worked perfectly well on my machine. It also worked perfectly well when I pushed it on our pre-production server. But then when I pushed it on our production server, it got broken.

The first problem I meet is this error, when trying to load a simple page using the `News` entity:

```
Error 500: Class 'Fidelise\SignUpBundle\Entity\News' does not exist
```

And yet that class definitely does exist.

The other problem is, when trying to log in to the website, I get this error:

```
500 - The request timed out.
```

Everything else works fine. Why would it start bugging when in production environment? I can also add some code if needed.

EDIT: here is the code of the call to the `News` class

```
/**
 * Display the news page
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function newsAction()
{
    $repositoryNews = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('FideliseSignUpBundle:News');
    $years          = $repositoryNews->getYears();
    $news           = $repositoryNews->getAll();
    return $this->render('@FOSUser/Security/news.html.twig', [
        'years'   => $years,
        'news'    => $news
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Did-you tested your app locally in production mode ?

Comment: Well I pushed it on the pre-production server, which is supposedly here to let us test the app before pushing it in production

Comment: Before pushed your site in pre-production, you have to test your app locally in production mode to avoid this kind of situation. Anyway show code related to the News entity call.

Comment: Okay, didn't know about that. I edited my question with the code

Comment: What's the News namespace ?

Comment: It's ```namespace Fidelise\SignUpBundle\Entity;```

Comment: @AdrienRosi any idea how to fix this?